Sending a message to multiple Locations on a GIS map in AnyLogic
I created a model in AnyLogic where I positioned an agent at multiple locations using an Excel sheet. The model correctly sets the locations on the GIS map, but I can't send a message to the destination. With every arriving order, I want to send a message "New delivery". To achieve this, I send the message from the sink block of the processflow of the sending agent. For that I created this function:
`for (Transshipment location : transshipments) { send("New delivery", location);
> }`

Since I have multiple locations, I've created the variable "location" with the type of the receiving agent. However, I received an error message stating that the message cannot be sent to a null destination.
I don't understand why the destination is null because my vehicle delivers the order to the correct location. I would appreciate your help.

hard to answer, you need to put on your Sherlock hat and go through this step by step using traceln() and other debugging tools. Which agent, when does it seem to "loose" the location... This is a core skill for building simulation models anyway so great exercise (and impossible to find from 1 screenshot here)
